# Render HTML properly for JSON text in Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am iterating through a list of props that consists of simple HTML markup

```
<div class="columns medium-4 large-4" v-for="keyOffer in keyOffers">
  <p>{{ keyOffer.head }}</p>
  <p>{{ keyOffer.sub }}</p>
</div>
```

and one of the props looks like this

```
keyOffers: [
  {
    id: 'offerSecond',
    head: '4G network',
    sub: 'Dedicated to bringing you the <span class="u_underline">best mobile service</span>
  },
]
```

but in the output the `<span>` gets printed and not applied.

Any help?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `v-html` directive:

```
<div class="columns medium-4 large-4" v-for="keyOffer in keyOffers">
  <p>{{ keyOffer.head }}</p>
  <p v-html="keyOffer.sub"></p>
</div>
```

**Ref:** [RawHTML](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)